# What kind of oil should I use to maintain my light stands?

Tags: equipment-protection

My Calumet light stands are starting to stick and become difficult to open.
I've cleaned them with WD40, but it didn't help much.
What else can I use to clean and/or lubricate my stands?

Comment: WD-40 is a cleaner, not a lubricant. It was originally meant to be a Water Displacing spray. The inventor claimed the formula was the 40th one he tried (hence: **W** ater **D** isplacement **-40** th formula). The oil used in it is so light that it will disperse fairly quickly and leave the contact surfaces dry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a general purpose lubricating oil, such as 3 in 1 (though I don't know if it's available where you are or if it's just a UK brand).

WD40 is probably to light an oil for long term lubrication.

Comment: +1 WD40 isn't really meant for lubricating, more for loosening stuck bolts.  It appears to be only 15% oil.  Get a light/medium grade oil or you could try a Teflon spray perhaps?

Comment: Thank you John.  Yes, I've heard of 3 in 1 oil.  I'll have to see where I can find some.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Around plastic parts, avoid any kind of oil-based lubricant. Oil eats plastic and rubber. Silicone lubricant, or graphite lubricant, is a safe bet. Of course, any household grade oil will work for metal parts, but apply it sparingly.